# What is the reverse operation of `.value_counts()` in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Starting from a non unique pandas series, one can count the number of each unique value by `.value_counts()`.

```
>> col = pd.Series([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0])

0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    3.0
4    3.0
5    3.0
dtype: object

>> stat = col.value_counts()
>> stat
3.0    3
1.0    2
2.0    1
dtype: int64
```

But, if starting from a data frame of two column, one for the unique values, while another for the number of occurrence. (`stat` in previous example). How to expand those into a single column.

Because I would like to calculate the median, mean, etc of the data in such a dataframe, I think describing a single column is much easier that two. Or is there any method to describe a 'value_count' dataframe derectly without expanding the data?

```
# turn `stat` into col ???

>> col.describe()
count    6.000000
mean     2.166667
std      0.983192
min      1.000000
25%      1.250000
50%      2.500000
75%      3.000000
max      3.000000
```

---

add testing data

```
>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["A", "B", "C"], "Value": [1,2,3], "Count": [2, 10, 2]})
>> df
  Name  Value  Count
0    A      1      2
1    B      2      5
2    C      3      2

df2 = _reverse_count(df)
>> df2
  Name  Value 
0    A      1 
1    A      1
2    B      2 
3    B      2
4    B      2  
5    B      2  
6    B      2  
7    B      2
8    C      3
9    C      3
```

Comment: can you clarify what would be the expected output for df ? repeat line 0 twice, line 1 10 times and line 2 twice ?

Comment: @fmarm exactly. I have update the testing example now.

Comment: I think I have the solution, I have updated my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `repeat` function from `numpy`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
col = pd.Series([1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0])
stats=col.value_counts()
pd.Series(np.repeat(stats.index,stats))
# 0    3.0
# 1    3.0
# 2    3.0
# 3    1.0
# 4    1.0
# 5    2.0
# dtype: float64
```

### Update :

for multiple columns you can use

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Count'])]
```

Comment: `v` is a single series in the answer. What I would like to do is manipulating a multiple column dataframe, and preseve other columns. Sorry about no clarifying this in the question.  But this solution works, I just need a little modifications, thank you very much.